# Axis label in month-year format ggplot2

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, axis-labels

I try to label the x-axis of my line graph in the format "Month-Year".

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
library(grid)
library(tidyr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(scales)
library(scales)

Listings100$Year<- as.Date(Listings100$Year)

p100 <- ggplot(Listings100, aes(x=Year, y=Listings, group=Neighborhood, 
colour=Neighborhood)) + geom_line()  +
labs(x = "", y = "Number of listings")+
scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1") +
scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%Y")) +
geom_line(size=1.1)
```

However, when plotting this the x-axis says "January-Year" although it actually should be "May-Year". Any ideas why the month is labelled incorrectly?

**Data**

```
structure(list(Year = structure(c(1273017600, 1304553600, 1336176000, 
1367712000, 1399248000, 1430784000, 1462406400, 1493942400, 1273017600, 
1304553600, 1336176000, 1367712000, 1399248000, 1430784000, 1462406400, 
1493942400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Neighborhood = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Cluster = c(100, 
    100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
    100, 100, 100), Listings = c(0, 0, 4, 10, 11, 30, 15, 6, 
    3, 8, 10, 16, 19, 51, 25, 42)), .Names = c("Year", "Neighborhood", 
"Cluster", "Listings"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: Try this `scale_x_date(breaks=Listings100$Year,  labels = date_format("%b-%Y")) `

Comment: Thank you, that's the solution :)